# How to show tags on tumblr when you hover over a picture?

Tags: css, hover, tumblr

I got this new theme (http://soeststhemes.tumblr.com/casual) but unfortunately it doesn't show the tags. I'd like to show the tags when you hover over an image, does anyone know how to do it on html?
Something like in this blog: http://yixing.tumblr.com/
Tags shows at the side when you hover your mouse on it

Comment: what exactly you want...?? Do you want to display some text while mouse over on any image...?

Comment: yeah, show the tags I used for that image when the mouse is over it

Answer (score 2):

Since this theme doesn't have tags, you're going to have to add them in. Take a look at [this useful guide](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#tags) tumblr has on creating custom themes.

First, you need the HTML for the structure. This is a simple section for the tags: a div box only appearing if the post has tags, with a link for each tag separated by a space. This must be pasted after each instance of `<div class="entry">` so that it shows for all types of posts.

```
{block:HasTags}
 <div id="tags">
  {block:Tags}<a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>&nbsp;{/block:Tags} 
 </div>
{/block:HasTags}
```

Now the CSS is what makes it appear and disappear upon hovering the post, as well as formatting it. This should be placed before `{CustomCSS}` in the HTML code, along with the theme's CSS. I added some extra lines to make the section more fluid with the theme.

```
#tags {
      /* Positions the tags section */
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      /* Sets opacity to 0 to hide */
      opacity: 0;
      filter: alpha(opacity=0);
      /* Keeps the tags section over everything */
      z-index: 10;
      /* Extra: Width is the same as the post width */
      width: 100%;
      /* Extra: Background colour */
      background: white;
      /* Extra: Smooth transition (same as theme) */
      -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease;
      transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

/* When hovering over .entry do this to #tags */
#entry:hover .tags {
      /* Opacity is maximum to show tags */
      opacity: 1;
      filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

Now it's just a case of tweaking the CSS to suit your needs. You can change the values of top or left, or change them to right or bottom. Negative values are also allowed.

You can see my example [here](http://shaunconnorway.tumblr.com/) using the theme you showed.

Comment: You'll probably want to use `.tags` instead of `#tags` since there will be multiple posts on the page at once.

Comment: +1 for that good point, thanks